# Getting data attributes from script code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

How can I console.log the data-text value in that javascript file? Noob here still learning. Thanks for the help or information..

Sample:
`<script type="text/javascript"  src="./test.js"  data-text="Hello World"></script>`

Comment: `console.log(document.currentScript.dataset.text)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) combined with the [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select the script like so

```
document.querySelector('script[data-text]').dataset.text
```